# UL now showing up as a numbered list

Tags: html, css

I have a website where I have lots of lists of links that are all  but they suddenly started showing up as numbered lists. I tried tinkering with the .CSS but cannot see how to fix it, and don't know why it suddenly changed. Any suggestions? I tried some of the suggestions on here but so far no luck!

TIA for any help you can offer, my HTML knowledge is rudimentary at best...

[This is one of the pages, they all have this problem.](http://www.needlesofsteel.org.uk/downloads.html)

This is the code for the list:

```css
.widget ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:circle;
}


.listwidget {
    position:relative;
}
.listwidget-title {
    margin-bottom:16px;
    margin-bottom:1rem;
    font-size:24px;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    font-weight:800;
}
.listwidget p {
    margin-top:0;
}
.listwidget ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
list-style-type:round;
    list-style-position: outside;
    margin:1em;
}
```

Comment: FYI: Thoroughly answering questions is time-consuming. If your question is solved, say thank you by accepting the solution that is best for your needs. The ✔ is below the ▲/▼ arrow, at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. You may also vote on the usefulness of an answer with the ▲/▼ arrow, if you have a 15+ reputation. Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question. [What should I do when someone's answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`round` is not a proper value for [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type), so browser changes it to the default.

Set it to ex. `disc`, and that's it.

```css
.listwidget ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: outside;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such value as `round` in `list-style-type`. Use either `circle` for or `disc` to show bullets or `none` to remove these.

```
list-style-type: circle;
```

or

```
list-style-type: circle;
```

or to remove

```
list-style-type: none;
```

Comment: Just tried both circle and disc, nothing has changed. Rats.

Comment: None makes no difference either. It's odd - I've had that website for years, and it changed a few months ago and I didn't do anything to the code...

Comment: OK I have numbers in Chrome and bullets in Edge. It would be nice if it was consistant!